# Bigcommerce Templates file missing

Tags: templates, bigcommerce

I am developing a template for bigcommerce site, where i want to show category list and some hard code links in the place of Page menu. Now what i do, just place this `%%Panel.SideCategoryList%%` in the upper navigation area. Which shows category list right.

But the problem is that i didn't find this `%%SNIPPET_SideCategoryList%%` file. (In snippets folder exist a file with this name, but that file doesn't work even if i remove all contents of that file.)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with SNIPPET_SideShopByBrandList.

I logged a ticket and got the following response:

> Thank you for contacting BigCommerce technical support.
>
> I see its reference in SideShopByBrand panel. In the same panel, there is another SNIPPET_ShopByBrandAllItem which is visible in snippets tree, but not this one. That's because its a hidden snippet, and its not possible to edit this.
>
> I have tested this in my personal store as well, and the output is same. let me know if you have any other questions.

I think yours might also be a "hidden snippet and not possible to edit"

Answer (score 0):

No worry....You need to just create html page and put the below code but keep one thing don't include the html, head, body etc

1) just create a html page and delete the html content 
2) put the below my code for 
3)

```
<li class="%%GLOBAL_LastChildClass%%"><a href="%%GLOBAL_CategoryLink%%">%%GLOBAL_CategoryName%%</a>
%%GLOBAL_SubCategoryList%%
</li>
```