# Bigcommerce: %%SNIPPET_SideCategoryList%% - where is the underlying template file?

Tags: templates, bigcommerce

In the file *template/Panels/SideCategoryList.html* there is line `%%SNIPPET_SideCategoryList%%`.

When I modify the file I think this line is referring to (*template/Snippets/SideCategoryList.html*) I see no change in the resulting output at all.

Any idea where the underlying template file is?

UPDATE: according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807282/bigcommerce-templates-file-missing?rq=1) it could be a 'hidden snippet' which can't be edited. Can anyone confirm this?  If so, what is the purpose of *template/Snippets/SideCategoryList.html*?

***template/Panels/SideCategoryList.html***

    `<div class="CategoryList" id="SideCategoryList">
        <h3>Categories</h3>
        <div class="BlockContent">
            <div class="%%GLOBAL_SideCategoryListTypeClass%%">
                %%SNIPPET_SideCategoryList%%
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`

***template/Snippets/SideCategoryList.html***

    `<li class="%%GLOBAL_LastChildClass%%"> 
        <a href="%%GLOBAL_CategoryLink%%"> %%GLOBAL_CategoryName%%</a>
        %%GLOBAL_SubCategoryList%%
    </li>`

As you can see from the above template code, between the Panels and Snippets *SideCategoryList.html* there isn't a `<ul>`.  Making changes to *template/Snippets/SideCategoryList.html* makes no difference.  This seems to point to `%%SNIPPET_SideCategoryList%%` pulling in code from elsewhere.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807282/bigcommerce-templates-file-missing?rq=1 it could be a 'hidden snippet'.  Can anyone confirm this?  If so what is the purpose of the file _template/Snippets/SideCategoryList.html_?

Comment: Can you show what changes you are trying to make to that file? I am able to edit the Snippet > SideCategoryList.html file just fine where the result is returned on the appropriate page.

Comment: In fact, _any_ changes made aren't reflected in the pages with a side category list. Eg. if I add an extra class to `<li>`.  Another reason it seems like another "hidden' SideCategoryList snippet is being used is that there isn't a `<ul>` present in either the  _Panels/SideCategoryList.html_ or _Snippets/SideCategoryList.html_ templates

Comment: Interestingly, I've noticed that the same template code (_Panels/SideCategoryList.html_) is used for both `#PageMenu #SideCategoryList` and also `.Left #SideCategoryList`.  Both these category lists have the SuperFish classes included in the `<ul>`.

Comment: I have to ask... Are you sure you're editing the right theme?

Comment: Are you updating via WebDav or the Bigcommerce design editor?

Comment: Yes - definitely the right theme and via WebDav

Comment: And you are able to make other changes to the template?

Comment: Yes - I can edit _Panels/SideCategoryList.html_ and other template files.  Just _Snippets/SideCategoryList.html_ seems to be the problem (that I've come across anyway).  Please see updated post.

Comment: Have you tried with just the snippet shortcode in the panel file (nothing else)? That is how it is on the site I'm looking at (where the snippet update works).

Answer (score 7):

Judging by the superfish classes being present on the ul, it sounds like you're using the 'Flyout menu' as the 'Category Menu Style' (This option can be found in Setup & Tools > Store Settings > Display).

When using the Flyout menu, the snippet that is being referenced is not 'Snippets/SideCategoryList.html'. Instead, try using the 'Snippets/FlyoutTree.html' and 'Snippets/FlyoutNode.html' templates.

Comment: You're right Clark - that fixed it. Appreciate your insight on that. No need for the CSS workaround now.

Comment: Unfortunately, that seemed to also remove the #PageMenu drop downs too.

Comment: The issue still remains that the theme developers instead of using a separate underlying template to list the categories for #PageMenu, .Left and the footer have used the same template. Another reason to markup semantically.  They could easily leave the SuperFish  default classes off, and apply it via a selector… eg. `$('#PageMenu .SideCategoryList ul.nav-menu').SuperFish(…);`